# Apache Pig Todate() function issue

Tags: apache-pig, to-date, string-to-datetime

I am converting a date string to datetime format in Pig using Todate function, but it is spitting out the wrong month.

```
input date = "2014-04-15 01:25:33.583Z" I am loading this as chararray
usage: ToDate(Timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS')
output : 2014-01-15T01:25:33.583Z
```

Any idea as to why this could be happening.

Comment: I found the mistake. The format was wrong.

Comment: what was the correct format ?

Answer (score 2):

The issues lies on the string format : the YYYY and DD should be in lowercase, while the months should stay in uppercase !

cf  : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

ToDate(Timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')

- only month and hour format need to be in capital letter.